# Formatting Cells in Google Sheets using API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following request body to change multiple cell colors to red. However only one cell is being updated to red. Any ideas?

```
{'requests': [{'updateCells': {'range': {'sheetId': 212797248,
 'startRowIndex': 1,
 'endRowIndex': 6,
 'startColumnIndex': 0,
 'endColumnIndex': 10},
'rows': [{'values': [{'userEnteredFormat': {'backgroundColor': {'red': 1}}}]}],
'fields': 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor'}}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
  {
    "requests": [
      {
        "repeatCell": {
          "range": {
            'sheetId': 1476957615, // 212797248,
            'startRowIndex': 1,
            'endRowIndex': 6,
            'startColumnIndex': 0,
            'endColumnIndex': 10
          },
          "cell": {
            "userEnteredFormat": {
              "backgroundColor": {
                "red": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment)"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Hi Mike! This worked great. Btw, If I want to use non primary colors such as grey? How do I do it?

Comment: Try with `{ red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5 }`, adjust the values

Comment: Oh so its rgb code combination. Got it. Appreciate your help.